# Passing uninitialized 2D Char Array into function

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, char, parameter-passing

I am trying to pass an uninitialized 2-D char array that is declared in main and define it in the function.

I am receiving a segmentation fault and the debugger says:

`Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004005af in initialize_world (array=0x7fffffffdff0, maxRows=6, 
    maxCols=5) at ec.c:33
33              array[i][j]='-';`

Here is the code for the prototype, main and the function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define ROWS 10
#define COLS 12


void initialize_world(char array[][COLS],int maxRows,int maxCols);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])  {
    char array[ROWS][COLS];
    int numOfRows, numOfCols; 

    numOfRows = 6;
    numOfCols = 5;

    initialize_world(array,numOfRows,numOfCols);

    return 0;
}   

void initialize_world(char array[][COLS],int maxRows,int maxCols)    {
    int i,j;   

    for(i=0; i < maxRows;i++)   {
        for(j=0; j < maxCols;i++)   {
            array[i][j]='-';
        }         
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have ROWS-numOfRows and COLS-numOfCols?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A banality, you're using i instead of j:

```
for(j=0; j < maxCols;i++)
```

Typo error, you should have written j++, that's why you overflow.

Comment: That's what happens with the copy/paste :P

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm glad I just made a simple mistake.

Comment: Yeah, better simple than complex, they're hard to fix :-)